# Timer.TimerPublisher doesn’t fire while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I tried to make a timer on SwiftUI, which worked just fine:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine    
struct ContentView: View {
let currentTimePublisher  = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 1.0, runLoop: .main, mode: .default)
    .autoconnect()

@State private var currentTime = Date()
var body: some View {

    VStack{
        Text("Time is:")
        Text("\(currentTime)")
        }.onReceive(currentTimePublisher) { (date) in
            self.currentTime = date
        }
    }
}
```

However, I tried to put the VStack in anything scrollable, be List, or ScrollView, I was not updating when I was scrolling the screen. It worked just fine when I didn't scroll.

I also put the TimerPublisher on the main thread as you can see, but that didn't change anything.

How can I make the SwiftUI update the time while I'm scrolling/interacting?

Comment: please show us your non working code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The scroll view runs the run loop in a different mode (not `.default`) while tracking touches. Use mode `.common` instead of mode `.default` to schedule the timer in the “common” run loop modes, which includes the scroll-tracking mode:

```
let currentTimePublisher  = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 1.0, runLoop: .main, mode: .common)
    .autoconnect()
```

Comment: Note that `.receive(on: )` call down the stream may not pass through the timer as it overrides the mode. So for example you still won't receive events if you have this:
`Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect().receive(on: RunLoop.main)`

Comment: In my case it turned out that not only I needed to change `.common` instead of `.default` as for the mode - but in addition, I also needed to change `DispatchQueue.main` instead of `RunLoop.main` in the receive subscription.