# Timer doesn't publish as intended

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a stopwatch using a Timer. The code works if I am not doing anything else, however, if I put it within my app, and I start interacting with the app (such as scrolling tab views, clicking buttons, etc.), the timer stops working.
I tried this: [Timer.TimerPublisher doesn’t fire while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58289023/timer-timerpublisher-doesn-t-fire-while-scrolling), but it also doesn't seem to work when I interact with the app.

```
struct Stopwatch: View {
    let stopwatch = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State var totalTime: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(totalTime))
                .onReceive(stopwatch) { _ in
                    totalTime += 1
                }
        }
    }
}
```

If scroll through the tabview, the text from the stopwatch view stops updating:

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @State var currentIndex = 0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 5) { index in
                    Color.black.tag(index)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
            .onChange(of: currentIndex) { _ in
                if currentIndex == 4 {
                    currentIndex -= 1
                }
            }
            ZStack {
                Capsule()
                    .foregroundColor(Color("GrayDisabled"))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 35)
                    .opacity(0.7)
                Stopwatch()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: it seems like this happens when there is an onChange modifier, as the bug doesn't happen when the modifier isn't there

Comment: " I start interacting with the app (such as scrolling tab views, clicking buttons, etc.)" -- it might be good to include at least one of the elements that seems to cause a problem in your example.

Comment: How do those two pieces of code relate?

Comment: @Yrb the bottom code contains the Stopwatch, however while I interact with the tabview, the stopwatch doesn't keep running until I stop the interaction

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to post the full structs, not just pieces of them.

Comment: @Yrb re-edited again with MRE that represents issue

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by creating two variables to 1. keep track of the Date of the start time and 2. to keep track of the elapsed time, updating the elapsed from calculating the difference of the current Date to the start Date.

```
@State private var startTime: Date = Date()
@State private var elapsed: TimeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince(Date())
```

```
.onReceive(stopwatch) { _ in
    let now = Date()
    elapsed = now.timeIntervalSince(startTime)
}
```

Also changed the timer to publish every 0.01 seconds instead of 1 second:

```
Timer.publish(every: 0.01, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```